# External String Call Causes Segfault in 32-bit, Works in 64-bit

Tags: c++

I am writing a program that calls an external string array from within a compiled static library.
When I compile and run the program in *64-bit*, it works without issue. However, when I try to call the external array when compiling code in* 32-bit*, it give a Segmentation Fault when running `main`.

Here is the code:

Header declaration "hoenyB_lib.h:

```
#ifndef HONEYB_LIB_H_
#define HONEYB_LIB_H_

#include <string>

 extern std::string honeyB_libs[];

#endif
```

Extern definition HoneyB_lib.cpp:

```
#include <string>

std::string honeyB_libs[] = { "libHoneyB.so", "libHoneyB3.so", "libHoneyB2.so", "" };
```

Extern use HoneyB_fcn.cpp:

```
deque<string> get_array()
{
    deque<string> dst;
    int i =0;

    for(;;)
    {
        if(honeyB_libs[i] == "")
            break;
        else
        {
            dst.push_front(honeyB_libs[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
    return dst;
}
```

The Makefile to compile this is as follows:

```
all:
    $(CC) -c -Wall -fPIC source.cpp
    $(CC) -g -c -fPIC honeyB_fcn.cpp
    ar rcs libHB.a honeyB_fcn.o
    g++ -g -c -fPIC honeyB_lib.cpp
    g++ --whole-archive -shared -o libHoneyB.so source.o honeyB_lib.o libHB.a
    g++ -L. -o main main.cpp -lHoneyB
```

This works without issue when main() is called. However, when I compile as *32-bit* with the following:

```
all32:
    $(CC) -m32 -c -Wall -fPIC source.cpp
    $(CC) -m32 -g -c -fPIC honeyB_fcn.cpp
    ar rcs libHB.a honeyB_fcn.o
    g++ -m32 -g -c -fPIC honeyB_lib.cpp
    g++ --whole-archive -m32 -shared -o libHoneyB.so source.o honeyB_lib.o libHB.a
    g++ -m32 -L. -o main main.cpp -lHoneyB
```

The code give a Segmentation Fault. If I remove the call in `honeyB_fct.cpp` to `honeyB_libs[]`, the code compiles and executes.

Does anybody have any idea why this fails for *32-bit*, but works for *64*?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the call to `get_array`?

Answer (score 0):

Order of initialization between different translation units is undefined.  You have no guarantee that global variables in `HoneyB_lib.cpp` will be initialized before they are used in `HoneyB_fcn.cpp`.  The only reason it worked for the 64-bit version is because you got lucky.

There are a couple workarounds:

1. Define the array in `honeyB_lib.h`, wrapped in an anonymous namespace to get around the ODR.  Each TU that includes your header will have its own copy of the array.
2. Again, define the array in the header, but put it inside of a function that returns the array.  The compiler *should* optimize it out everywhere, but if not you can make the array static in the scope of the function and return by reference (i.e. make it a singleton).

As a side note, I'd recommend a `std::array` instead of a raw array; this will let you do `honeyB_libs.size()` (or even `for (auto&& lib : honeyB_libs) {...}`) instead of relying on the `""` sentinel value, which would clean up your `get_array` function a bit.

Comment: All global variables should still be initialized before `main`, so if you call `get_array` in usual code instead of in some global variable’s initialization this isn’t the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help. It appears that the problem had to do with the bit count of strings in *32-bit* vs *64-bit*. Changing *honeyB_libs[]* from a string array to a const char* array solved the issue.
honeyB_lib.h

```
extern const char* honeyB_libs[];
```

honeyB_lib.cpp

```
const char* honeyB_libs[] = { "libHoneyB.so", "libHoneyB3.so", "libHoneyB2.so", "" }
```

function.cpp

```
deque<string> get_array()
{
   deque<string> dst;
   string temp;
   int i =0;

   for(;;)
   {
    if(strlen(honeyB_libs[i]) == 0)
        break;
    else
    {
        temp = honeyB_libs[i];
        dst.push_front(temp);
        i++;
    }
   }

  return dst;
}
```

Doing this allows my program to compile and run as *64-bit* and *32-bit*